# How to shift columns in a particular row in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

After sorting given data I got the problem on the picture above. How to shift values in a first row (`Life Made WI-Fi Touchscreen Photo Frame`) to the right by one? So Category will be empty, Rating will become 1.9, Reviews -  19.0, etc. Should mention that I tried `pd.shift` method, but didn't get the clue how to point a particular row. I used the following data: https://github.com/qingweihk/Profitable-App-Profiles-for-the-App-Store-and-Google-Play-Markets

So here is my code:

```py
import pandas as pd
google_play_data = pd.read_csv('googleplaystore.csv')
>>>google_play_data.head(10)

sorted_by_installs = google_play_data.sort_values('Installs', ascending = False)
>>>sorted_by_installs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update

Leaves first column along and shifts other values down one:

```
df.iloc[df.index.get_loc(10472), 1:] = df.iloc[df.index.get_loc(10472), 1:].shift()
```

Ouput:

```
App               Life Made WI-Fi Touchscreen Photo Frame
Category                                              NaN
Rating                                                1.9
Reviews                                                19
Size                                                 3.0M
Installs                                           1,000+
Type                                                 Free
Price                                                   0
Content Rating                                   Everyone
Genres                                                NaN
Last Updated                            February 11, 2018
Current Ver                                        1.0.19
Android Ver                                    4.0 and up
Name: 10472, dtype: object
```

---

You can do this:

```
df.loc[10472] = df.loc[10472].shift()
df.loc[10472]
```

output:

```
App                                                   NaN
Category          Life Made WI-Fi Touchscreen Photo Frame
Rating                                                1.9
Reviews                                                19
Size                                                 3.0M
Installs                                           1,000+
Type                                                 Free
Price                                                   0
Content Rating                                   Everyone
Genres                                                NaN
Last Updated                            February 11, 2018
Current Ver                                        1.0.19
Android Ver                                    4.0 and up
Name: 10472, dtype: object
```

Comment: This isn't quite what you want.  I don't think.

Comment: Thank you. The issue is solved now. I also swapped ```App``` and ```Category``` columns: ```google_play_data.loc[10472,['App','Category']] = google_play_data.loc[10472,['Category','App']].values```

Comment: @DimaSidukov Great... I looked at the data and realized you need to do that, I just rewrote the shift above to handle it.  Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using df.iloc[index] to target the row?